# passing data to and from Vue/React app in Netsuite Suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Ok so basically what I need is as follows. I have managed to display a VueJS App using a Suitelet.
What I'm unsure of is how I should be passing data back and forth. In the end what I need to build is some sort of table with filters to display data dynamically... I can't figure out what the best way to send the query's from the VueApp and then get the data back from netsuite would be.

I considered using a second Suitelet as a API, making it external and then using that as a way to receive query's and send back data... I understand that this method is unsecure and not recommended so what are my other options and how would they be implemented?

TIA

Comment: If you want data outside of NS, the `Suitelet` is an optimal solution. `BUT` as you mentioned it needs  a layer of security(_csrf, recaptcha, etc). If you are in NS environment, a `Restlet` is a better solution as it forces the user to be log in ;). Anyway, both have the same http methods, get, post, delete... methods.

Comment: So the app is internal to NetSuite.... I think I'm going to use one Suitelet to host the "app" and a second one as a controller to handle axios calls... Hopefully it works.